Build Pipeline inside Docker Container
I am trying to initiate a build pipeline from Github Actions. The host runner is on Azure VM. The step inside the workflow initiate a docker build as follows:
  - name: Build inside a Docker Container
    run: docker build --build-arg PACKAGE_VERSION=${{ env.PACKAGE_VERSION }} -t frameworkdiagcr01.azurecr.io/v5frameworkdiagbuild:1.0 -f .\V5FrameworkDiagnostics\build.dockerfile .
    shell: pwsh

Inside the build.dockerfile it contains the following among others:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build

WORKDIR /V5FrameworkDiagnosticsBuild


COPY . ./


RUN powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-ChildItem -Path ."

The workflow hangs while running the powershell command and eventually throw the following error:
Step 6/9 : RUN powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-ChildItem Path ."
---> Running in 8de9422e91fe
container 8de9422e91fe0e9582f82688a8beddf14b34c28e7fd1cc7062b7cbfb3ccdbd5f encountered 
an error during hcs::System::Start: context deadline exceeded
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

